# Missing method in template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

1. How does one make sure, that the specialization of a (class) template implements all 
   functions? (Right now only when I use `mul` do I get an error message.)
2. What is the difference between the specialization to int for traits1/traits2. I thought they were both template specializations, but traits2 does not accept `static` and gives a linker error instead of a compiler error.

.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct traits1{
  static T add(T a, T b) { return a+b; } /* default */
  static T mul(T a, T b);                /* no default */
};

template<>
struct traits1<int> {
  static int add(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
  /* static int mul(int a, int b) missing, please warn */
};

template<typename T>
struct traits2{
  static T add(T a, T b);
  static T mul(T a, T b);
};

template<>
int traits2<int>::add(int a, int b) { return a*b; }

/* traits2<int>::mul(int a, int b) missing, please warn */

int main()
{
  std::cout << traits1<int>::add(40, 2) << "\n";
  // error: mul is not a member of traits1<int>
  //std::cout << traits1<int>::mul(40, 2) << "\n";

  std::cout << traits2<int>::add(40, 2) << "\n";
  // error: undefined reference to traits2<int>::mul(int, int)
  //std::cout << traits2<int>::mul(40, 2) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't specialize the whole class if all you want is different behavior for one particular function. Specialize that function alone:

```
template<>
int traits1<int>::add(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
```

You can't make sure a specialization implements the all template methods, because they're unrelated.

2) You didn't provide a definition for `traits2::mul`, so of course you get the linker error - the declarations is there.

Comment: 1) I want to specialize all functions, this was just test what happens when a function is missing.


2) But why is the error message different between traits1 and traits2? I'd expect both to complain that mul is missing (in the same way)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann if you did specialize all functions, you wouldn't get the error, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann 2) It's the same error - "prog.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `traits1<int>::mul(int, int)'
prog.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `traits2<int>::mul(int, int)'" see http://ideone.com/uCeJz

Comment: How do I make sure, that all functions are implemented? If  I miss a function, there is no error, unless someone actually uses the template. I just want to provide the templates and make sure I didn't miss something.

Comment: @LuchainGrigore They give different errors: see http://ideone.com/B83BW. Only if you removed line 9-12 (and thus make them equal), do they give the same error.

Comment: 1) Why is a template specialization unrelated to the unspecialized one? 2) What is the difference between the specialization of traits1 and traits2

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann in the code you posted - http://ideone.com/B83BW - there's no linker error, because it didn't get to linking.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann 1) tells me you didn't understand what templates are. 2) you didn't specialize traits2, only a single method.

Comment: `traits1<int>` gets `mul is not a member of traits1<int>` because the full specialization of `traits1<int>` has nothing to do with the default `traits1`: There is no `mul()` in `traits1<int>`. `traits2<int>` gets `undefined reference to traits2<int>::mul(int, int)` because that function is declared but not defined.

Comment: To generate easy to understand errors for missing definitions, use [Boost.Concept Check](http://www.boost.org/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm). Definitions will always be only linker error, but most people define members of templates inline, because there is no compelling reason not to (they are usually short and have to be in the header anyway).